# How do I remove a Fakes assembly from a Visual Studio 2012 project?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, microsoft-fakes

I've added a [Fakes assembly](http://www.peterprovost.org/blog/2012/04/15/visual-studio-11-fakes-part-1) to a Visual Studio 2012 C# unit test project, via the "Add Fakes Assembly" reference context menu option. What's the procedure to completely remove the Fakes assembly, i.e. to undo my adding it to the project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the references to the fake project assembly, after that it will underline the using statements that used the removed references with red, so that will help you completely remove any leftover reference. This of course is a manual approach, if you require a different approach use a 3rd party tool like resharper for example.

Comment: That can hardly be enough, considering that it will leave behind at least the Fakes\<reference>.fakes file?

Comment: that's not a problem, you can delete them directly from the filesystem, as long as they are dereferenced there will be no problem.

Comment: So that's the whole procedure you would say, remove the reference to *.Fakes assemblies and delete the file Fakes\<reference>.fakes?

Comment: thats one way of doing it, the other way would be as i said to use a specialized third party tool for this purpose, or why not build your own after thouroghly reading documentation about fakes.

Answer (score 10):

As of Visual Studio 2012 RTM, to completely remove a Fakes assembly from a unit test project, you need to:

- Remove the .Fakes file from the Fakes folder in your project
- Remove the .* files from the (hidden) FakesAssemblies folder in your project
- Remove .Fakes assembly reference from the project